# I am working with pipe delimited files which go off my screen horizontally. I wish to pivot the data so that each horizontal line becomes a column

Tags: excel, text, editor, delimiter

I am working with pipe delimited files which go off my screen horizontally. I wish to pivot the data so that each horizontal line is displayed vertically. A solution in MS-Excel would work, or a dedicated text-editor (such as "UltraEdit," "Notepad++" or "Sublime Text" would also work)

For example, the original pipe-delimited file is:
[image: How it's showing now...]

I want it to be shown, like so:
[image: How I wan tit to show...]

I want to be able to edit these fields, and save the file in the original horizontally formatted file that I started off with. The focus is on being able to see the line numbers, making the fields easier to edit.

I have tried using Excel and it opens my file and places each element in the original format within a cell, but within 3 rows, horizontally. I need "Names, "Fruits" and "Cars" to be turned into columns, not rows.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is easy in two steps.

1. Select the column with the data and use `Text to Columns` in the Data tab of the Ribbon: selecting 'Delimeted' and 'Other' and entering the pipe character.
2. Copy the resulting range and right-click a cell where you want the transposed data to go. Select 'Paste Special' and then check the Transpose box. Click OK.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Say we have a text file like:

[image]

Running this short macro:

```
Sub ImportFile()
   Dim j As Long, k As Long
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\stuff.pipe" For Input As #1
    j = 1
     Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, TextLine
            ary = Split(TextLine, "|")
            k = 1
            For Each a In ary
               Cells(k, j) = a
               k = k + 1
            Next a
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

will produce this in the worksheet:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So, let's say I have made the edits I wanted to. Now how would I save this file (with edited fields) and preserve the same structure I started off with?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Linux or OSX you could use tpose to do it in one command:

```
$ cat data.txt
Names,john,billy,sally,david
fruits,apple,banana,orange,grapes
cars,toyota,honda,nissan,ford

$ tpose -d, data.txt
Names,fruits,cars   
john,apple,toyota   
billy,banana,honda  
sally,orange,nissan 
david,grapes,ford
```

It works pretty well if you have big data files too. You can grab it here:
https://bitbucket.org/jmsmistral/tpose